# No value in both Local Value and Master Value Column - phpInfo

Tags: logging, php

I just learnt how to deploy php website in to my hosting. But I found out that I need to track my `error_log` and `mail.log` for tracking purposes. When I tried to follow some guides, I tried making "`test.php`" file that `echo-ing phpinfo();` and when I checked the info, under Configuration core, the directive `error_log` and `mail.log` has "no value"(row) in both Local Value and Master Value (column). Since I'm newbie maybe I forgot to something. How will I create them inside my ftp hosting? Will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: If you can't edit the `php.ini` file, create the file, then `ini_set('error_log', './error.log');`? (preferably put it outside of your webroot) http://php.net/ini_set

Comment: hi there, is it okay to put it outside the webroot?